# Textview: Replace text between wildcard to smaller text

Tags: android, regex

From a string, I need to make text between wildcard smaller.

Ex:
orange "apple" banana

"apple" need to apple in smaller font.

Part of the answer was probably a regex to catch text between "*".

Update: I've found that "*(.*?)*" may be a good way to catch the substring

Answer (score 1):

> Pattern.compile("\\"([\w]+)\\"");

Comment: May I ask for more context?  (how to modify font?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708576/11552503 but in your case, you would have group(1) instead of that and pattern would be what I mentioned above..